# Defaulting the first array value to a drop down list

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to default the first value of a json array object to a drop down list

```
  <select ng-model="selectedItem"  ng-options="item as item.taskName for item in abc.taskList"  ng-init="selectedItem = selectedItem || abc.taskList[0].taskName">
      <pre>{{selectedItem | json}}</pre>
</select>
```

I have tried ng-init and setDefault, but nothing worked. Every time a blank option values comes first then comes the taskList values.

this is how my array looks like

```
  $rootScope.abc = {
          taskList: [{
            'projectId': '',
            'taskId': '',
            'taskName': ''
        }]
     };
```

Here is the json array Object

```
{
"returnCode": "0",
"returnMsg": "Success",
    "taskList": [{
        "taskId": "123",
        "taskName": "TimeSheet"
    }, {
        "taskId": "345",
        "taskName": "Travel Expense"
    },{
        "taskId": "653",
        "taskName": "Attendance"
    }]
}]
```

}

How do I default TimeSheet as the default value in the dropdown list?

Comment: remove 'taskName' from `ng-init="selectedItem = selectedItem || abc.taskList[0].taskName"`. If your data is returned asynchronously you'll have to set the selected value when the data is returned

Comment: Also, ng-init is clearly documented as something you should ,never use (except in a single convoluted case). Put that initialization code in your controller.

Comment: @devqon, Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately removing taskName din't help me here

Comment: By adding `ng-model="selectedItem = abc.taskList[0].taskName" ` , I got the whole stuff working  :)  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1

Set: `ng-options="item.taskName as item.taskName for item in abc.taskList"`

```
 <select ng-model="selectedItem"  
      ng-options="item.taskName as item.taskName for item in abc.taskList" 
      ng-init="selectedItem = selectedItem || abc.taskList[0].taskName" >      
 </select>
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/orkpak2v/)</kbd>

In `ng-init` you use `abc.taskList[0].taskName` a.e. `taskName` therefore to make it work we need ot use model as `item.taskName as item.taskName`

---

#### Option 2

Set `selectedItem` as `abc.taskList[0]`

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"  
   ng-options="item as item.taskName for item in abc.taskList" 
   ng-init="selectedItem = abc.taskList[0]">      
</select>
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/b9r8d89g/)</kbd>

Comment: While using Demo1,I got the option like: 
`<select ng-options="item.taskName as item.taskName for item in abc.taskList">
`**`<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="TimeSheet" selected="selected" > TimeSheet</option> `**`
</select>`
But the list didn't appear with TimeSheet value defaulted/selected.

_Demo2 gave me this result_

`<select ng-init="selectedItem = abc.taskList[0]">
  ** <option value="?" selected="selected"></option> **
    <option value="string:TimeSheet" label="TimeSheet"> TimeSheet</option>
 </select>`
Which also was not defaulting.

Comment: @Chris in Demo1 you have one working and one not working example. In demo 2 both show results. I opened it in Chrome

Comment: I got it working  :) 

This is what I added  `ng-model="selectedItem = abc.taskList[0].taskName" `  along with your provided options. Appreciate your time in resolving my issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using this `ng-selected="$first"` you will get first value as selected in dropdown.

Comment: I got it working by adding `ng-model="selectedItem = otlProject.ieTaskList[0].taskName" `   :)

Comment: Okay... I did this way and it's working for me. So I am just trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set first value  Your scope List in controller  Like that

```
$scope._yourscope.projectId= ($scope.taskList.length > 0) ? $scope.taskList[0].projectId: '';
```